# To have smaller font in this table of presentation

Tags: tables, beamer

My code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Nobel Prizes in Bioelectromagnetism}

{\fontsize{0.3em}{0.3em}               % TODO Problem here!
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | c | c |}
\hline 
Year &  Name of recipient &  Nationality & Subject of research \\ \hline
1901 &  Jacobus van't Hoff *) & The Netherlands & laws of chemical dynamics     
and osmotic pressure  \\ \hline
1903 &  Svante Arrhenius *) & Sweden & theory of electrolytic
dissociation \\ \hline
1906 & Camillo Golgi, Santiago Ramón y Cajal & Italy Spain & work on the structure of nervous system \\ \hline
1920 & Walther Nernst *) & Germany   & work in thermochemistry \\ \hline
1924 & Willem Einthoven & The Netherlands & discovery of electrocardiogram mechanism \\ \hline
1932 & Edgar Douglas Adrian, Sir Charles Sherrington & Britain & discoveries regarding function of neurons \\ \hline
1936 & Sir Henry Hallet Dale, Otto Loewi & Britain, Germany & work on chemical transmission of nerve impulses \\ \hline
1944 & Joseph Erlanger, Herbert Spencer Gasser & U.S. & researches on differentiated and functions of nerve fibers \\ \hline
1949 & Walter Rudolf Hess & Switzerland & discovery of function of middle brain \\ \hline
1961 & Georg von Békésy & U.S. & discoveries of the physical mechanism of the inner ear \\ \hline
1963 & Sir John Eccles, Alan Lloyd Hodgkin, Andrew Fielding Huxley & Australia, Britain & study of the transmission of nerve impulses along a nerve fibre \\ \hline
1967 & Ragnar Arthur Granit, Haldan Keffer Hartline, George Wald & Finland, U.S., U.S. & discoveries about chemical and physiological visual processes in the eye \\ \hline
1968 &  Lars Onsager *) & U.S. &    work on theory of thermodynamics of irreversible processes \\ \hline
1970 &  Julius Axelrod, Sir Bernard Katz, Ulf von Euler & U.S., Britain, Sweden & discoveries concerning the chemistry of nerve transmission \\ \hline
1981 &  David Hunter Hubel, Torsten Nils Wiesel & U.S., Sweden & discoveries concerning information processing in the visual system \\ \hline
1991 &  Erwin Neher, Bert Sakmann & Germany, Germany & discoveries concerning the function of single ion channels in cells \\ \hline
1997 & Paul D. Boyer, John E. Walker, Jens C. Skou *) & U.S., U.K., Denmark & the enzymatic mechanism underlying the synthesis of ATP; discovery of an ion-transporting enzyme, Na+, K+ -ATPase \\ \hline
2003 &  Peter Agre, Roderick MacKinnon *) & U.S., U.S & discoveries concerning channels in cell membranes \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but I get

[image]

**How can you alter the font size in the table of Beamer?**

Comment: You need `\selectfont` after `\fontsize{...}{...}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is *just*, but only just possible to make the table fit in a beamer frame by (a) using the `\tiny` font size directive, (b) using column types for the second and fourth columns that allow the material to wrap, and (c) squeezing the intercolumn whitespace settings. Given the tiny font size, don't expect the audience to be able to read much of the material...

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Nobel Prizes in Bioelectromagnetism}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default value: 6pt
\tiny  %%  command to change the font size
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l P{1.4in}  l  Y @{}}
\hline
Year &  Name of recipient &  Nationality & Subject of research \\ \hline
1901 &  Jacobus van't Hoff *) & The Netherlands & laws of chemical dynamics
and osmotic pressure  \\ \hline
1903 &  Svante Arrhenius *) & Sweden & theory of electrolytic
dissociation \\ \hline
1906 & Camillo Golgi, Santiago Ramón y Cajal & Italy Spain & work on the structure of nervous system \\ \hline
1920 & Walther Nernst *) & Germany   & work in thermochemistry \\ \hline
1924 & Willem Einthoven & The Netherlands & discovery of electrocardiogram mechanism \\ \hline
1932 & Edgar Douglas Adrian, Sir Charles Sherrington & Britain & discoveries regarding function of neurons \\ \hline
1936 & Sir Henry Hallet Dale, Otto Loewi & Britain, Germany & work on chemical transmission of nerve impulses \\ \hline
1944 & Joseph Erlanger, Herbert Spencer Gasser & U.S. & researches on differentiated and functions of nerve fibers \\ \hline
1949 & Walter Rudolf Hess & Switzerland & discovery of function of middle brain \\ \hline
1961 & Georg von Békésy & U.S. & discoveries of the physical mechanism of the inner ear \\ \hline
1963 & Sir John Eccles, Alan Lloyd Hodgkin, Andrew Fielding Huxley & Australia, Britain & study of the transmission of nerve impulses along a nerve fibre \\ \hline
1967 & Ragnar Arthur Granit, Haldan Keffer Hartline, George Wald & Finland, U.S., U.S. & discoveries about chemical and physiological visual processes in the eye \\ \hline
1968 &  Lars Onsager *) & U.S. &    work on theory of thermodynamics of irreversible processes \\ \hline
1970 &  Julius Axelrod, Sir Bernard Katz, Ulf von Euler & U.S., Britain, Sweden & discoveries concerning the chemistry of nerve transmission \\ \hline
1981 &  David Hunter Hubel, Torsten Nils Wiesel & U.S., Sweden & discoveries concerning information processing in the visual system \\ \hline
1991 &  Erwin Neher, Bert Sakmann & Germany, Germany & discoveries concerning the function of single ion channels in cells \\ \hline
1997 & Paul D. Boyer, John E. Walker, Jens C. Skou *) & U.S., U.K., Denmark & the enzymatic mechanism underlying the synthesis of ATP; discovery of an ion-transporting enzyme, Na+, K+ -ATPase \\ \hline
2003 &  Peter Agre, Roderick MacKinnon *) & U.S., U.S & discoveries concerning channels in cell membranes \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you abbreviate all first and middle names and drop all "Sir" appellations in the second column, replace all instances of "Britain" with "U.K." in the third column, and get rid of all inessential preamble-type stuff in the final column -- strings such as "discoveries concerning", "work on", "work in", and "study of the" -- you should be able to save several lines and thus have enough space for a footer for this table. While you're at it, you may also want to get rid of most horizontal lines (and, if you wish, replace them with a bit more vertical whitespace) and use the line-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package for the three remaining lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Nobel Prizes in Bioelectromagnetism}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default value: 6pt
\tiny  %%  command to change the font size

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l l  l  Y @{}}
\toprule
Year &  Name of recipient &  Nationality & Subject of research \\
\midrule
1901 &  J. van't Hoff$^{ *}$ & Netherlands 
& Chemical dynamics and osmotic pressure  \\[2pt]
1903 &  S. Arrhenius$^{ *}$ & Sweden 
& Electrolytic dissociation \\[2pt]
1906 & C. Golgi, S. Ramón y Cajal & Italy, Spain 
& Structure of nervous system \\[2pt]
1920 & W. Nernst$^{ *}$ & Germany   
& Thermochemistry \\[2pt]
1924 & W. Einthoven & Netherlands 
& Electrocardiogram mechanism \\[2pt]
1932 & E. D. Adrian, C. Sherrington & U.K. 
& Function of neurons \\[2pt]
1936 & H.H. Dale, O. Loewi & U.K., Germany 
& Chemical transmission of nerve impulses \\[2pt]
1944 & J. Erlanger, H.S. Gasser & U.S. 
&  Functions of nerve fibers \\[2pt]
1949 & W.R. Hess & Switzerland 
& Function of middle brain \\[2pt]
1961 & G. von Békésy & U.S. 
& Physical mechanism of the inner ear \\[2pt]
1963 & J. Eccles, A.L. Hodgkin, A.F. Huxley & Australia, U.K. 
& Transmission of impulses along nerve fibres \\[2pt]
1967 & R.A. Granit, H.K. Hartline, G. Wald & Finland, U.S., U.S. 
& Chemical and physiological visual processes \\[2pt]
1968 &  L. Onsager$^{ *}$ & U.S. 
& Thermodynamics of irreversible processes \\[2pt]
1970 &  J. Axelrod, B. Katz, U. von Euler & U.S., U.K., Sweden 
& Chemistry of nerve transmission \\[2pt]
1981 &  D.H. Hubel, T.N. Wiesel & U.S., Sweden 
& Information processing in the visual system \\[2pt]
1991 &  E. Neher, B. Sakmann & Germany, Germany 
& Function of single ion channels in cells \\[2pt]
1997 & P.D. Boyer, J.E. Walker, J.C. Skou$^{ *}$ & U.S., U.K., Denmark 
& Enzymatic mechanism underlying synthesis of ATP; Ion-transporting enzyme, Na+, K+ -ATPase \\[2pt]
2003 &  P. Agre, R. MacKinnon$^{ *}$ & U.S., U.S 
& Channels in cell membranes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 and +1 in mind for "Given the tiny font size, don't expect the audience to be able to read much of the material...". :-) What a pity that it is impossible to write the cited sentence here at, say, 2 pt.

Comment: I have footer also so I have a problem with the last line. How can you make the height 1.5 lines more compact?

Comment: @Masi - Can you replace all first and middle names with initials? That would likely save several lines.

Comment: I will do it. Just out of curiosity. Is it technically possible to get the table any smaller?

Comment: @Masi - I've posted an addendum to address your follow-up question. I would *not*, repeat *not* make the font any smaller than it already is.