# How to adjust this tabularx in Beamer frame size?

Tags: beamer, tabularx, debian

I am thinging how to format the table fit the frame size nicely in LaTeX. 
I can recall that `\tiny`/... is not the optimum option here. 
Code which output in Fig. 1

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetheme{Berkeley} 
\logo{
%% llx lly urx ury
\includegraphics[trim=8cm 2cm 11cm 2cm,clip, height=\headheight, width=\headheight]{example-image}
}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % Not needed!
\begin{document}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384801/13173
\section{1. skills}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lorem}

% Maybe this one TODO but not \tiny https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208763/13173
\begin{table}[]
\centering
%\caption*{Test}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|}
\hline
Avain lorem & V2 & V1 & V0 & START lorem & P1 & P2 & P3 & Kriittinen lorem \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=football,radio,default=-0]{Do you play football?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\item \ChoiceMenu[name=ice-hockey,radio,default=-0]{Do you play ice-hockey?}{Much (2)=2,Little (1)=1,Not at all (0)=0}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output in Fig. 1

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

Proposal tabular format there but I think `adjustbox` is the worst what you can do

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,center}
\begin{table}[hpt]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Avain lorem & V2 & V1 & V0 & START lorem & P1 & P2 & P3 & Kriittinen lorem \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &  & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Output in Fig. 2

[image]

OS: Debian 9
TeXLive: 2017

Comment: @TeXnician Any specific approach for Beamer frame size?

Comment: Why should there be one? Your table is clearly too wide for the page. It doesn't matter if it's a beamer page or not, you have to shrink the table's width to make it fit.

Comment: Why do you (mis-)use `tabularx` if you don't use any `X` column?

Comment: @samcarter I am trying to figure it out but cannot get it run.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions in the duplicate question, you could also use a plain frame without the sidebar which will give you a bit more horizontal space.

Comment: @samcarter Please, see the body. Adjustbox approach done but I think it is the worst you can do here. Any better proposals?

Comment: There are other suggestions (like rotating the column headers) in the answer to the linked question.